# Find out the difference in two dataframe with same column pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have three dataframe as shown below

df1:

```
Unit_ID        Price
1              10
2              20
3              10
```

after one day df1 is updated as df2 as shown below.

df2:

```
Unit_ID        Price
1              10
2              20
3              10
4              15
5              20
```

after one day from that day df2 updated as df3 as shown below.I would like to find out the new unit in the current dataframe as shown below.

df3:

```
Unit_ID        Price
1              10
2              20
3              10
4              15
5              20
6              80
```

I would like to write a function to return new unit with its dataframe in pandas.
I would like to find out the new unit in the current dataframe as shown below.

For example in first update it should below data frame

df:

```
Unit_ID        Price
4              15
5              20
```

In Next update it should return below dataframe

df:

```
Unit_ID        Price
6              80
```

steps
1. Make sure that in each dataframe Unit_ID is unique.
2. Find out the new Unit_ID in current table.

Comment: How are updated data? What is code for it? Is not possible see what new data are added?

Comment: @jezrael I think data is updated daily. I would like find the new Units daily. But don't have that code. Currently I am assuming df3 is updated latest, df2 is previous to that and so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each day is necessary copy `DataFrame` to new one:

```
df1 = df.copy()
```

and after adding new rows you can use test membership by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with inverted mask by `~`:

```
df_added = df[~df['Unit_ID'].isin(df1['Unit_ID'])]
```

Verifying solution:

```
print (df2)
   Unit_ID  Price
0        1     10
1        2     20
2        3     10
3        4     15
4        5     20

print (df3)
   Unit_ID  Price
0        1     10
1        2     20
2        3     10
3        4     15
4        5     20
5        6     80

df_added = df3[~df3['Unit_ID'].isin(df2['Unit_ID'])]
print (df_added)
   Unit_ID  Price
5        6     80
```

Comment: is the above code will work for if the Unit_ID is of type int

Comment: @ALI - It is not important of type, only necessary unique values.

Comment: if data is updated using kafka, can you please help me how to incorporate this code with kafka.

Comment: @ALI - Sorry, never working with kafka, maybe you can create new question with kafka tag.

Comment: @ALI - Added code for verify solution, can you explain more not working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205802/discussion-between-ali-and-jezrael).